# How can I change my svn profile on visual studio 2013

Tags: svn, version-control, visual-studio-2013, ankhsvn, assembla

I have already connected to a svn profile but I want to change my
account with another account. How can I make it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suppose you're using `AnkhSVN` in Visual Studio 2013. Ankh is known to be a little hard to make a way around SVN tasks sometimes.

Have you tired using another SVN client like `Tortoise SVN`?

Comment: Yes I am using AnkhSVN , I want to change my svn profile in my project , not to use another svn client